# Jquery DataTable column Filter Datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have created a Table using the Jquery Datatable api and it works great, I have also implemented the jquery code to have the filter on each column (at the bottom) of the table and it works great.

I have a column called "Start Date" and I want to have its filter to be a datepicker instead of an input that the user type, could you please help me do that.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.13/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({ 


        "scrollCollapse": false,
        "paging":         true
    }
    );


    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );


     $('#example tbody')
        .on( 'mouseenter', 'td', function () {
            var colIdx = table.cell(this).index().column;

            $( table.cells().nodes() ).removeClass( 'highlight' );
            $( table.column( colIdx ).nodes() ).addClass( 'highlight' );
        } );


    $('#button').click( function () {
        alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
    } );

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>

<style>
tfoot input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
tr.highlight {
    background-color: blue !important;
}

</style>





<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33429/filter-with-a-date-picker  perfect working example here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these links at the top of your script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.13/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Then this code at the top of your document ready function.

```
$( function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );

// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    if (title === "Start date") {
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        }
        else {
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        }
} );
```

here is it working on code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJGRpy

Comment: Haha Thanks, glad I could help :)

Comment: Hello I would appreciate if you can help me with this, I need to create a date range filter to filter all records that are between a start date and the end date, I have create a question for this but the answer that I got did not solve it, could you please tell me what I should fix, here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096331/jquery-datatables-date-range-filter/42099771?noredirect=1#comment71374870_42099771