# Jquery Datatables Date Range Filter

Tags: jquery, datatables

The code below is working perfectly but I need to add a new functionality to allow the user to filter on a range of records based on their start date and end date, the user should be able to get all the records in between, I was able to find a datatables page tutorial to implement this but I was not able to add that to the code, can you please help me, here is the link

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_dates

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#datepickerStart").datepicker();
    $("#datepickerEnd").datepicker();
  });

  // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
  $('#example tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    if (title === "Start date") {
      $(this).html('<input type="text" id="datepickerStart" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    } else if (title === "End date") {
      $(this).html('<input type="text" id="datepickerEnd" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    } else {
      $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    }
  });

  // DataTable
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({


  });







  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });


  $('#example tbody')
    .on('mouseenter', 'td', function() {
      var colIdx = table.cell(this).index().column;

      $(table.cells().nodes()).removeClass('highlight');
      $(table.column(colIdx).nodes()).addClass('highlight');
    });


  $('#button').click(function() {
    alert(table.rows('.selected').data().length + ' row(s) selected');
  });

  // Apply the search
  table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;

    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
      if (that.search() !== this.value) {
        that
          .search(this.value)
          .draw();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
tfoot input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

tr.highlight {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.13/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>End date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th id="min">Start date</th>
      <th id="max">End date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>2011/04/27</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>2011/04/29</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>2011/04/28</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>2012/03/30</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>2008/11/30</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>2012/12/21</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put that code anywhere within your javascript after you build the table.

You just have to change these lines like so:

```
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
  var iFini = document.getElementById('datepickerStart').value; 
  var iFfin = document.getElementById('datepickerEnd').value; 
  var iStartDateCol = 4; 
  var iEndDateCol = 5; 

    iFini=iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(0,2);
    iFfin=iFfin.substring(6,10) + iFfin.substring(3,5)+ iFfin.substring(0,2);

    var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);
    var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2);

    if ( iFini === "" && iFfin === "" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( iFini <= datofini && iFfin === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( iFfin >= datoffin && iFini === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);
```

Comment: Hello, I have added the code and you line as well as the cdn of that plugin, but the page is not loading properly, see below the full code

Comment: That code goes under this: `function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {` See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/filtering/row-based/range_dates.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.13/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( function() {
         $( "#datepickerStart" ).datepicker();
          $( "#datepickerEnd" ).datepicker();
        } );

        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            if (title === "Start date") {
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" id="datepickerStart" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                }
            else if (title === "End date") {
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" id="datepickerEnd" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                }
                else {
                                    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                }
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({ 

      $('#min').keyup( function() { table.draw(); } );
      $('#max').keyup( function() { table.draw(); } );

        }
        );


        var iFini = document.getElementById('datepickerStart').value; 
        var iFfin = document.getElementById('datepickerEnd').value; 
        var iStartDateCol = 4; 
        var iEndDateCol = 5; 


        $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        var iFini = document.getElementById('fini').value;
        var iFfin = document.getElementById('ffin').value;
        var iStartDateCol = 6;
        var iEndDateCol = 7;

        iFini=iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(0,2);
        iFfin=iFfin.substring(6,10) + iFfin.substring(3,5)+ iFfin.substring(0,2);

        var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);
        var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2);

        if ( iFini === "" && iFfin === "" )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iFini <= datofini && iFfin === "")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iFfin >= datoffin && iFini === "")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);




        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        } );


         $('#example tbody')
            .on( 'mouseenter', 'td', function () {
                var colIdx = table.cell(this).index().column;

                $( table.cells().nodes() ).removeClass( 'highlight' );
                $( table.column( colIdx ).nodes() ).addClass( 'highlight' );
            } );


        $('#button').click( function () {
            alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
        } );

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );






    </script>

    <style>
    tfoot input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 3px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    tr.highlight {
        background-color: blue !important;
    }

    </style>





    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>End date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th id="min">Start date</th>
                    <th id="max">End date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>2011/04/27</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>2011/04/29</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>2011/04/28</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>2012/03/30</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>2008/11/30</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>2012/12/21</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thank you, were you able to load that html page ? I just copy/pasted your code and the page did not load for me ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if helps but i do the thing you ask like this

**EDIT**

Here more explanation. The $.fn.DataTable.ext.search it's the API provided for Datatables to extend the functions of filtering. First there is an array wich has the names of the tables who has to apply the function below (this is in case there is more than one table on the same page), then gets the value from de datepickers and split for create another Date who has the same format in the three cases (From, To and StartDate). Then compares that dates between them and filter as appropiate. The StartDate is from the current record of the Table.

At the datepickers i added the class **date-range-filter**

```
var allowFilter = ['tableOT'];

$('.date-range-filter').change(function() {
            oTable.draw();
        });

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          // check if current table is part of the allow list
          if ( $.inArray( settings.nTable.getAttribute('id'), allowFilter ) == -1 )
          {
              // if not table should be ignored
              return true;
          }
          var min = $("#<%=txtFechaDesde.ClientID %>").val();
          var max = $("#<%=txtFechaHasta.ClientID %>").val();
          var fromDate;
          var toDate;
          // need to change str order before making  date obect since it uses a new Date("mm/dd/yyyy") format for short date.
          var d = data[0].split("/");
          var startDate = new Date(d[1]+ "/" +  d[0] +"/" + d[2]);
          if(min != ""){
              var fd = min.split("/");
              fromDate =  new Date(fd[1]+ "/" +  fd[0] +"/" + fd[2]);
          }
          if(max != ""){
              var td = max.split("/");
              toDate =  new Date(td[1]+ "/" +  td[0] +"/" + td[2]);
          }

          if (fromDate == null && toDate == null) { return true; }
          if (fromDate == null && startDate <= toDate) { return true;}
          if(toDate == null && startDate >= fromDate) {return true;}
          if (startDate <= toDate && startDate >= fromDate) { return true; }
          return false;
      }
    );
```

Comment: Could you offer more explanation?