# Datatable datefilter loads correctly but throws Uncaught TypeError on date selection

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

This question is just a replication of scenario given [Jquery Datatables Date Range Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096331/jquery-datatables-date-range-filter). The datatable loads correctly but throws following error when selecting a date. The following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined
    at Datepicker._selectDay (jquery-ui.1.12.1.js:8188)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.selectDay (jquery-ui.1.12.1.js:8789)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.dispatch (jquery.v1.12.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.r.handle (jquery.v1.12.0.min.js:3)
```

**Examining**
This issue is well known. For example if datepicker element id is "**#datepickerStart**", it should be loaded only once in given page. If two DOM element has this same element id, above error will be thrown.

We used it mainly for individual field search as given in [Jquery Datatables Date Range Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096331/jquery-datatables-date-range-filter). When I inspected developer tools in browser, I could see two DOM having "#datepickerStart" generated. One in search area which is correct and the other just at the end of table area.

I am confused how these duplicate table columns are generated by following code. Please know that **this happens when  either injecting below code or putting raw HTML for search text boxes**:

```
$('#example tfoot th').each(function (){
    var title = $(this).text();

    if (title === "Start date") {
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" id="datepickerStart" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );

    } else if (title === "End date") {
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" id="datepickerEnd" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );

    } else {
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    }
});
```

Do I miss something or I do it the wrong way? I cross-checked that I didn't initialize datatable twice or created datePicker element twice.

Could you please help sort out where it goes wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
The table structure is created as follows,

```
<table id='example' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>End date</th>
                <th>Duration</th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>End date</th>
                <th>Duration</th>  
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: any reason you don't put the html straight into the table footer html?

Comment: @Bindrid I don't understand your question but my table structure looks as given above (just edited in question) before initializing datatable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something for you to play with, see it here: http://jsbin.com/haxaror/edit?html,js,output

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // my dates did not fit yours so this simple loop fixes that
    for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; ++i) {
        dataSet[i].start_date = startdates[i];
        dataSet[i].end_date = enddates[i];
    }
    // Column defs (just the way i do it)
    var col = [
        { data: "first_name" },
        { data: "last_name" },
        { data: "position" },
        { data: "office" },
        { data: "start_date", type: "date" },
        { data: "end_date", type: "date" },
        { data: "salary" }
    ];

    var thistable = $('#example').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        select: { style: 'single' },
        columns: col,
        dom: 'frtip',
    })

    // Apply the search including date columns. Datepicker will not allow invalid dates
    thistable.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;
        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            that
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
        });
    });


    $("#datepickerStart").datepicker(
    {
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", changeYear: true,
      onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
          thistable.column(4)
             .search(dateText)
             .draw();
          }
      });
    $("#datepickerEnd").datepicker(
    {
       dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", changeYear: true,
       onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
           thistable.column(5)
               .search(d)
               .draw();
           }
       });
});
```

Comment: This is really nice. I achieved the same results by using **thistable.column(5).search(d).draw();** API yesterday almost the same time you wrote this answer. Though the issue can't be fixed directly, the approach allows the intended datepicker functionality to be alive.

Comment: do you consider it's a datatable bug since datatable auto-creates the table columns one more time in document body?

Answer (score 1):

Your raw html is static form what I see so why not put your search box straight in to the code:

```
    <table id='example' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>End date</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="text" placeholder="Search URL"/></th>
                <th><input type="text" placeholder="Search Title"/></th>
                <th><input type="text" placeholder="Search User"/></th>
                <th><input type="text" id="datepickerStart" placeholder="Search Start Date"/></th>
                <th><input type="text" id="datepickerEnd" placeholder="Search End Date"/></th>
                <th><input type="text" placeholder="Search Duration"/></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

But having said all this, I think you are looking in the wrong area for your error.  show use your data structure and the .DataTable() I suspect that there is something wrong with the columns definition not matching the json exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried raw HTML as you suggested. It didn't work. It still creates duplicate search box having ID "datepickerStart". Totally there are 2  "datepickerStart" IDs in HTML body. I even removed the code responsible for creating dynamic search fields. It gets created automatically though.  I checked JSON data, all data looking good. start date has format "2017-08-03 09:16:58.00", "2017-08-14 03:37:57.00" which is correct API response. We just use "yy-mm-dd" format in datepicker ignoring the time segments.  I don't know where it goes wrong.

Comment: I added API response for better understanding. Search for "API response" above.

Answer (score 0):

This issue doesn't have proper resolution, but a related answer can be found in this post [Datepicker returning uncaught typeError: undefined 'currentDay'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17781425/1786360)
Please continue all your suggestions and answers in [Datepicker returning uncaught typeError: undefined 'currentDay'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17781425/1786360)  I am closing this post since no consistent behavior is found even in linked page yet.